# get the message definition in c++

Tags: ros, roscpp, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

i would like to get the ros message defintion file as a string in c++. Similar to how it is done in python ...

Where I just have to call:

```
rosmsg.get_msg_text("sensor_msgs/Joy")
```

and get the following output:

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
float32[] axes
int32[] buttons
```

The message type is not known before compile time ... Thus, everything I have is a string in the following format

```
std::string strType = "sensor_msgs/Joy"; // or something else like = "std_msgs/String" ...
```

so i need a method or a function which takes in a string, defining the package and the message type ... and want to get out a string with the complete message definition ...

But like it is done in python, not only the content of sensor_msgs/msg/Joy.msg, which is:

```
Header header           # timestamp in the header is the time the data is received
float32[] axes          # the axes measurements from a joystick
int32[] buttons         # the buttons measurements from a joystick
```

I need the extracted format of all nested message definitions like presented in the first example ...

I think this is also possible somehow in roscpp, but I could not figure it out yet, thanks for any suggestions ...

Cheers ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50298/get-the-message-definition-in-c++/) by [andre__](https://answers.ros.org/users/3775/andre__/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use **ros::message_traits::Definition<*Type*>::value()**. Following your example, to print the definition of `sensor_msgs/Joy` to the console, simply write:

```
std::cout << ros::message_traits::Definition<sensor_msgs::Joy>::value() << std::endl
```

This assumes you have the appropriate includes.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2017-09-13**:
For this to be possible, all the message headers that will eventually be used should be available at compile time. I think an approach using strings only would be way more flexible and can cover all kinds of messages.